# AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'dx'

Tags: python

Programando el juego PONG en el módulo turtle de Python me salta este error:

```
    wn.onkeypress(pada_down,"Down")
 ball=turtle.Turtle()
 ball.speed(0)
 ball.shape("square")
 ball.color("green")
 while True:
    ball.setx(ball.xcor()+ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor()+ball.dy)
    if ball.ycor()>290:
        ball.sety(290)
        ball.dy*=-1


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#71>", line 2, in <module>
    ball.setx(ball.xcor()+ball.dx)
AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'dx'
```

No entiendo el porqué de este error de atribución concretamente en "dx" cuando en "dy" no parece haber mayor problema.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, veo que no existe atributo dx en la clase Turtle (realmente nunca la he usado), pero qué es para ti dx.? en dy no sale error porque el script se atasca en dx y no alcanza dy, si comentas dx, te saltará el mismo error en dy.

Comment: Falta parte del codigo necesario para ayudarte con mas antecedentes. Sin embargo te puedo adelantar que no se alcanza a evaluar la linea que llama a dy por lo que no es evidente que no tiene problemas. Claramente esa clase no posee aquel atributo, posiblemente no posea dy tampoco.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias a los dos, quisiera poder responder a vuestras cuestiones de cara a aportar más información, pero me veo incapaz.. No tengo muy claro a qué hace referencia .dx (sencillamente estaba siguiendo un tutorial y emolándolo); en ese punto concretamente trataba de establecer "bordes" en la pantalla, límites que inviertan el movimiento de la bola. Siento no poder ser más claro.

Comment: SOLUCIÓN: Para quien le interese; no había definido previamente el valor de dx. En este caso, dx (o delta de X; variación de X...) representaba el movimiento (en píxeles) de un elemento. Solucionado.